# AUTH0: Server-side verification of universally logged-in user?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, auth0

I'm building a NUXT front-end with a separated server back-end on ExpressJS and I'm trying to implement Auth0.

The callback works, and I get logged into the front end successfully as expected. But next, I want to ask the server to create a DB record of the logged in user and manage metadata on the server-side. The problem is, I don't know what I need to consume on the browser-side and pass to the server so that the server can verify the user's login is valid. I see that an **access_token** is present in the callback URI which flashes before the user is forwarded to the page they were trying to access.

**THE QUESTION**:
My question is, how can I pass **access_token** to the server for the server to then validate that the user logged in is indeed valid, and retrieve that user's Auth0 details with it?

I've configured my application as a **Regular Web Application**. I'm utilizing the @nuxtjs/auth plugin to integrate Auth0, and my nuxt.config.js file contains the following settings for the auth strategy:

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      // Relative to axios baseURL?
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/logout',
      callback: '/callback',
      home: '/',
    },
    strategies: {
      auth0: {
        domain: '<--hide->.us.auth0.com',
        client_id: '<------------hide-------------->',
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't auth0 already have a means of associating app-specific metadata with an account? https://auth0.com/docs/users/metadata

Comment: @Ouroborus, Yes it does, but I am using Firebase. I need to associate a LOT of relational data with the user, and I don't think Auth0 is really the place for that.

Comment: I would think the usual strategy is to associate a UUID with the user's app metadata and then use that same UUID as the effective user id with respect to your database.

Comment: @Ouroborus My intent was to let Auth0 be the authority on users, and inject those users into my own database. Given that, wouldn't the UUID simply be the auth0 userid?

Comment: You are indeed correct.

Comment: Ok, follow-up question then...  If I'm able to retrieve that auth0 userid when the user logs in to place it into my database, how can my server be sure it's authentic?

Comment: Security is a complex topic. You should probably review the docs for auth0, especially [Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens) and [Common Threats](https://auth0.com/docs/security/prevent-common-cybersecurity-threats).

Comment: @Ouroborus, THANK YOU!... This conversation got me on the right path, researching the right information and I landed on this guide which was EXACTLY what I was looking for: https://hashinteractive.com/blog/nuxt-authentication-auth0-provider-management-api/